leaky shower faucet knob - how to find right compression stem?
I have a leaky faucet knobs (pics and video below), and I'm wondering what part I need to purchase to fix it (a particular compression stem?).
For context, here is a video of how the faucet leaks.
https://youtube.com/shorts/Jse28Zx4ftA

remove the handle
unscrew the top nut
under it there is small seal
replace it
